# Magento 2.2: Unable to unserialize value?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2-dev, unserialize

Running into issues on a site running **Magento 2.2.0-rc3.0/PHP 7.0.23**

The following issue occurs with all 3rd party extensions either enabled or disabled.

When adding an item to comparison from category or product page or submitting a review from product page we get the following error in the browser:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to unserialize value.

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to unserialize value.
#0 /home/___/public_html/app/code/Magento/Theme/Controller/Result/MessagePlugin.php(157): Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json->unserialize('[{\\"type\\":\\"su...')
#1 /home/___/public_html/app/code/Magento/Theme/Controller/Result/MessagePlugin.php(135): Magento\Theme\Controller\Result\MessagePlugin->getCookiesMessages()
#2 /home/___/public_html/app/code/Magento/Theme/Controller/Result/MessagePlugin.php(84): Magento\Theme\Controller\Result\MessagePlugin->getMessages()
#3 /home/___/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Theme\Controller\Result\MessagePlugin->afterRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#4 /home/___/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#5 /home/___/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#6 /home/___/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#7 /home/___/public_html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#8 /home/___/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#9 {main}
```

The error does not go away unless you clear cookies, in particular, the mage-messages cookie.
[image]

Any assistance in troubleshooting these errors is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't that a core bug? is there a GitHub issue for this?

Comment: this will give you an idea https://www.scommerce-mage.com/blog/solved-unable-to-unserialize-value-magento-2.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out to be a permissions issue, where magento was setting permissions for generated files that were restricted on this server.

Solved by creating magento_umask file in the root directory with the appropriate umask for the server.

See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/post-install-umask.html for additional details.

Comment: Hello, I am facing the related issue like this.
Can you please look in to [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225745/magento-2-2-2-rest-api-i-need-to-change-the-customer-password-using-rest-api) .

Comment: @chunk all my dir are 755,and files are 644, what is the appropriate umask to set? tia

Answer (score 98):

I was able to resolve this issue by Flushing my Redis Cache from the CLI

```
redis-cli flushall
```

I hope this helps future users.

Comment: Nicely done. This should probably be the accepted answer.

Comment: It seems to not always be the solution. In my case I do not even use redis (yet)

Comment: thanks. i restarted varnish, thinking that would flush it, but this did the trick.

Comment: it works for me

Comment: This helped me while upgrading from 2.2.9 to 2.3.2. I got the error when I executed  php ***bin/magento setup:upgrade;***

Comment: amazing! finally things working with this.

Comment: Thank you @craig. This worked for me

Comment: Needed to clear cookies aswell to get rid of this error at frontend

Comment: No redis cache. Had to delete cache files from var/cache/ to fix the issue.

Answer (score 36):

The problem is in /vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php there is a function unserialize($string) which gives you a syntax error if string is serialized (not json but php serialization).

There is a workaround - you can check if string is serialized (vs json-encoded) and then use serialize($string). Change unserialize to:

```
public function unserialize($string)
{
    if($this->is_serialized($string))
    {
        $string = $this->serialize($string);
    }
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
         throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');

    }
    return $result;
}
```

and add function to check if string is serialized:

```
function is_serialized($value, &$result = null)
{
    // Bit of a give away this one
    if (!is_string($value))
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Serialized false, return true. unserialize() returns false on an
    // invalid string or it could return false if the string is serialized
    // false, eliminate that possibility.
    if ($value === 'b:0;')
    {
        $result = false;
        return true;
    }
    $length = strlen($value);
    $end    = '';
    switch ($value[0])
    {
        case 's':
            if ($value[$length - 2] !== '"')
            {
                return false;
            }
        case 'b':
        case 'i':
        case 'd':
            // This looks odd but it is quicker than isset()ing
            $end .= ';';
        case 'a':
        case 'O':
            $end .= '}';
            if ($value[1] !== ':')
            {
                return false;
            }
            switch ($value[2])
            {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 9:
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        case 'N':
            $end .= ';';
            if ($value[$length - 1] !== $end[0])
            {
                return false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    if (($result = @unserialize($value)) === false)
    {
        $result = null;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

After save fe. category without problem, You can restore class to default and there wont be such problem in future.

Comment: Its working 100% fine for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: it is not working ... :-(

Comment: Check what happens if the value a:0:{} is passed. Go line by line. What happens if the result of unserialize is passed to a strong typed method that is expecting an array? You might want to change your answer.

Comment: Fixed the issue in my case

Answer (score 31):

In my case, I patched as follows to unserialize a serialized string: 
File: /vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php

Find:

```
public function unserialize($string)
{
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

replace by:

```
public function unserialize($string)
{
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        if(false !== @unserialize($string)){
            return unserialize($string);
        }
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but it's not working as expected. Have anyone tried this and if got it works, please help me

Comment: What issues you were facing?

Comment: The issue got fixed. Thanks for asking!

Comment: Grt... Thank you!!!

Comment: dont edit core files!!!! use preference if you want to change this, but really you should be deserializing your strings in the db. See here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196216/magento-2-2-error-unable-to-unserialize-value#answer-196946

Comment: Thanks @MageLearner , It also working in 2.3.1 after migrate the data from magento 1 to magento 2

Comment: Worked for me while upgrading from 2.2.8 to 2.3.3.

Comment: It is working for me. The issue raised after upgrading from Magento 1 to Magneo 2.3.3.

Comment: @Aji, this is an old thread but running into similar error when the site is in developer mode while trying to 'edit' any customer records, any clues since above code changes are not working in Magento 2.2.6?

Comment: @cnu Is it a migrated database from Magento 1 ?

Comment: @Aji, No. I believe the issue is due to 3rd party extension code, so yet to figure out what it is.

Comment: @cnu I debug this issue on my local environment. I believe Its a serialized data that is stored in the customer database table. If you encounter error for particular customer. Then please find out Is there any serialized data stored for that customer ? If so please delete the serialized data.  The error will gone.

Comment: Saw this error after upgrading from Magento 2 CE 2.2.6 to 2.3.6 for any bin/magento commands such as bin/magento cache:clean. Making changes suggested here resolved 'Unable to unserialize value222. Error: Syntax error' issue.

Answer (score 26):

Do not edit core files for solution. Override following way
Just put following line in di.xml inside etc directory

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json" type="Namespace\ModuleName\Serialize\Serializer\Json" />
```

And inside Namespace\ModuleName\Serialize\Serializer Directory: file Json.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Serialize\Serializer;



class Json extends \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json
{


    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * @since 100.2.0
     */
    public function unserialize($string)
    {
      if($this->is_serialized($string))
        {
            $string = $this->serialize($string);
        }
        $result = json_decode($string, true);
        if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
             throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');

        }
        return $result;
    }


    function is_serialized($value, &$result = null)
    {
    // Bit of a give away this one
        if (!is_string($value))
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Serialized false, return true. unserialize() returns false on an
        // invalid string or it could return false if the string is serialized
        // false, eliminate that possibility.
        if ($value === 'b:0;')
        {
            $result = false;
            return true;
        }
        $length = strlen($value);
        $end    = '';
        switch ($value[0])
        {
            case 's':
                if ($value[$length - 2] !== '"')
                {
                    return false;
                }
            case 'b':
            case 'i':
            case 'd':
                // This looks odd but it is quicker than isset()ing
                $end .= ';';
            case 'a':
            case 'O':
                $end .= '}';
                if ($value[1] !== ':')
                {
                    return false;
                }
                switch ($value[2])
                {
                    case 0:
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                    case 5:
                    case 6:
                    case 7:
                    case 8:
                    case 9:
                        break;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            case 'N':
                $end .= ';';
                if ($value[$length - 1] !== $end[0])
                {
                    return false;
                }
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        if (($result = @unserialize($value)) === false)
        {
            $result = null;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Works perfectly

Comment: The implementation is flawed. What happens if the value a:0:{} is passed to Json:unserialize method? Is it the desired behaviour? What is the point of the result variable in is_serialized method? It's not returned and it doesn't have impact over anything as at method call no variable is passed as second argument.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution, and is much better than the post above to edit the file directly in vendor. More than likely, you'll have to run the setup upgrade task locally and then again on staging/production, so it'll have to persist environments and vendor/ directory is an artifact created at build time.

Comment: @vitoriodachef I'm facing the exact case you have mentioned. Do you have found any solution?

Comment: I have used following function to decide
**private function isSerialized($value)
    {
        return (boolean) preg_match('/^((s|i|d|b|a|O|C):|N;)/', $value);
    }**

Comment: DIdn't work. I had to manually change all entries in the DB from `a:0:{}` to `[]`

Comment: This one works.

Comment: Glad to know it.. @Pini

Answer (score 6):

After flushing Redis the issue has sorted.
Thank you **Craig** for the solution.

I'm using port 6379 for cache, so I run command :

```
redis-cli -p 6379 flushall
```

Comment: 6379 is already the default port; you should update the [existing answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/196825/92968) instead of duplicating it.

Answer (score 3):

It's mostly related with Redis cache, so try to flush out this with simple command in your SSH

redis-cli flushall

Comment: Please upvote the [existing answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/196825/92968) instead of duplicating it.

Answer (score 3):

For what it is worth, the above approach did not work for me and I found that an empty string was being passed to the unserialize function. Doing a check and returning an empty array solved my issue. It's a hack, but was able to move on.

```
public function unserialize($string)
{
    if(empty($string)){
        return [];
    }

    if ($this->is_serialized($string)) {
        $string = $this->serialize($string);
    }
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Your solution has worked for me. Any idea about why its generating this issue?

Comment: No idea. But felt it is was most likely due to a Magento 1 migration.

Answer (score 2):

Sameers' answer above worked for me although i had to use different code in the block.

```
public function serialize($data)
{
    $result = json_encode($data);
    if (false === $result) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to serialize value.');
    }
    return $result;
}

function is_serialized($value, &$result = null)
{
    // Bit of a give away this one
    if (!is_string($value))
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Serialized false, return true. unserialize() returns false on an
    // invalid string or it could return false if the string is serialized
    // false, eliminate that possibility.
    if ($value === 'b:0;')
    {
        $result = false;
        return true;
    }
    $length = strlen($value);
    $end    = '';
    switch ($value[0])
    {
        case 's':
            if ($value[$length - 2] !== '"')
            {
                return false;
            }
        case 'b':
        case 'i':
        case 'd':
            // This looks odd but it is quicker than isset()ing
            $end .= ';';
        case 'a':
        case 'O':
            $end .= '}';
            if ($value[1] !== ':')
            {
                return false;
            }
            switch ($value[2])
            {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 9:
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        case 'N':
            $end .= ';';
            if ($value[$length - 1] !== $end[0])
            {
                return false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    if (($result = @unserialize($value)) === false)
    {
        $result = null;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function unserialize($string)
{
    if($this->is_serialized($string))
        {
        $result = $this->serialize($string);
        }
    $result = json_decode($string, true);

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally found this issue reared it's head running the command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

After a migration. I found out that I was missing the "**crypt**" hash key in `src/app/etc/env.php`:

```
<?php
return [
    'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'admin'
    ],
    'crypt' => [
        'key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    ],

    ...
```

Ensure this is not empty and preferably matches your projects' other environments!

Comment: I left crypt key empty during installation expecting a new one to be generated, which clearly does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the error in a CMS page in front end.

It was the Magento widget code in the CMS Page Content that was causing problem(which I copied from another source). I deleted the widget code and inserted the same widget using the Insert Widget button in the CMS Page edit screen and it worked.

The above process formatted the widget code differently and it made the error go away.

Answer (score 1):

ROOT directory 
1. `public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php`

[Download JSON.php](https://gist.github.com/manojind/9f18bbecaeb3e2bbfb056a634ade62a2)  https://gist.github.com/manojind/9f18bbecaeb3e2bbfb056a634ade62a2

**2. Just replace below  function (unserialize) and add new function OR just download the attached file and replace with default**

```
public function unserialize($string)
{
    if($this->is_serialized($string))
    {
        $string = $this->serialize($string);
    }
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
         throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');

    }
    return $result;
}
```

**3. Add new function :**

```
function is_serialized($value, &$result = null)
{

    if (!is_string($value))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if ($value === 'b:0;')
    {
        $result = false;
        return true;
    }
    $length = strlen($value);
    $end    = '';
    switch ($value[0])
    {
        case 's':
            if ($value[$length - 2] !== '"')
            {
                return false;
            }
        case 'b':
        case 'i':
        case 'd':
                       $end .= ';';
        case 'a':
        case 'O':
            $end .= '}';
            if ($value[1] !== ':')
            {
                return false;
            }
            switch ($value[2])
            {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 9:
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        case 'N':
            $end .= ';';
            if ($value[$length - 1] !== $end[0])
            {
                return false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    if (($result = @unserialize($value)) === false)
    {
        $result = null;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: My issue not fixed..please help me

Answer (score 0):

I found out that whole serialized data cannot be fit into a database MySQL table column with `TEXT` data type. 
I just found the column `flag_data` value of `system_config_snapshot` line is trimmed.

I had to change it to `MEDIUMTEXT` for this column `flag.flag_data`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to run sql directly but i did that for save my time.
Just run this query

```
ALTER TABLE flag MODIFY flag_data LONGTEXT;
UPDATE flag SET flag_data = '{"system":"","scopes":"","themes":""}' WHERE flag_code = 'config_hash';
UPDATE flag SET flag_data = '{}' WHERE flag_code = 'system_config_snapshot';
```

Answer (score 0):

Was same error. 
When tried to update database(ver 2.2.6) with fresh code (ver 2.3.2).

For  fix - runned

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on 2.3.0 or greater you will want to use the solution provided by MageLearner. The older way with case statements is obsolete. If you don't use MageLearner's solution on 2.3.0 or greater; you will hit all sorts of problems with viewing order data and configurable products.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Magento 2.3.3 with Mailchimp installed. When I updated my Mailchimp to the latest version the error disappeared:
https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento2/releases/tag/102.3.41
You can also see in there release notes that they fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json instead of  Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Serialize to decode or encode JSON object and then the error were disappeared.