# After upgrading magento version 2.1.0 to 2.2.1 getting error unable to unserialize value

Tags: magento2.2, unserialize

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to unserialize value.

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to unserialize value.
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-widget/Helper/Conditions.php(59): Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json->unserialize('a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s...')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/Block/Product/ProductsList.php(259): Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions->decode('a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/Block/Product/ProductsList.php(236): Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList->getConditions()
#3 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/CatalogWidget/Block/Product/ProductsList/Interceptor.php(50): Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList->createCollection()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-widget/Block/Product/ProductsList.php(216): Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList\Interceptor->createCollection()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(666): Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList->_beforeToHtml()
#6 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/CatalogWidget/Block/Product/ProductsList/Interceptor.php(817): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList\Interceptor->toHtml()
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('71feee93b718ea1...')
#9 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('71feee93b718ea1...')
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('71feee93b718ea1...')
#11 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('71feee93b718ea1...', true)
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('71feee93b718ea1...')
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content')
#14 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#16 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', true)
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content')
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main')
#19 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#21 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', true)
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main')
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns')
#24 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#26 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', true)
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns')
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content')
#29 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#31 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', true)
#32 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content')
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#34 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#35 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#36 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', true)
#37 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#38 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper.ou...')
#39 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper.ou...')
#40 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper.ou...')
#41 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper.ou...', true)
#42 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper.ou...')
#43 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#44 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#45 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#46 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#47 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(954): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#48 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#49 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', Array)
#50 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#51 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#52 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(257): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#53 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#54 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#55 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#56 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#57 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#58 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#59 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#60 /var/www/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#61 {main}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194010/magento-2-2-unable-to-unserialize-value