# Magento 2.2.2, Unable to unserialize value, magento_umask and edting Json.php did not help

Tags: json, magento2.2.2, unserialize

After upgrade I'm getting below error in my local :

```
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to unserialize value.

#0 myPath/vendor/magento/module-theme/Controller/Result/MessagePlugin.php(157): Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json->unserialize('[{\\"type\\":\\"su...')
```

Tried solutions in below link but none of them helped :(

[some solutions here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194010/magento-2-2-unable-to-unserialize-value)

Comment: Magento 2.2.2 has changed serialize into json format. so we need to do those changes manually . we are also faced same issue while upgrade magento 2.1.4 into magento 2.2.1. we have created category and all manually .

Comment: Perfect Solution available Here: >[Solved: Unserialize Value Magento 2.2.2](https://magecomp.com/blog/solved-unable-to-unserialize-value-magento-2-2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding a line in function `unserialize` of class `Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json`.

This does happen when magento send some invalid string to parse or add string with multiple slashes to the string.

Even you can check exact error from this `json_last_error()` method.

So for now add `stripslashes` at the very first line of method body.

so your function should look like this:

```
public function unserialize($string)
    {
        $string = stripslashes($string);
        $result = json_decode($string, true);
        if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue in the **file /vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php**, run this command:

```
public function unserialize($string)
{
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        $result = @unserialize($string);
        if($result){
            return $result;
        }
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Unable to unserialize value. Error: " . json_last_error_msg());
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Hope this helps!