# Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

Tags: magento2.2

> 1. Unable to Unserialize value error after upgrading Magento to 2.2.2

For this i have followed the solution from here:
[Magento 2.2: Unable to unserialize value?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194010/magento-2-2-unable-to-unserialize-value) by @Sameer Bhayani
and overrided the Json file of **Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json**

But after that i was getting the below error:

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in /home/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Helper/Product/Configuration.php on line 118
```

Please Advise.

Comment: did you found any solution? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and solved by below steps:

**Step 1** : Change the following file `/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php` especially the unserialize function.

Here is the original unserialize function -:

```
public function unserialize($string)
{
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Change the above function to the following -:

```
public function unserialize($string)
{
    /* Added the following if clause to resolve the issue */
    if($this->is_serialized($string)){
        $string = $this->serialize($string);
    }
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
         throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Also add the following `is_serialized` function in the same file `/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php`

```
function is_serialized($value, &$result = null)
{
    // Bit of a give away this one
    if (!is_string($value))
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Serialized false, return true. unserialize() returns false on an
    // invalid string or it could return false if the string is serialized
    // false, eliminate that possibility.
    if ($value === 'b:0;')
    {
        $result = false;
        return true;
    }
    $length = strlen($value);
    $end    = '';
    switch ($value[0])
    {
        case 's':
            if ($value[$length - 2] !== '"')
            {
                return false;
            }
        case 'b':
        case 'i':
        case 'd':
            // This looks odd but it is quicker than isset()ing
            $end .= ';';
        case 'a':
        case 'O':
            $end .= '}';
            if ($value[1] !== ':')
            {
                return false;
            }
            switch ($value[2])
            {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 9:
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        case 'N':
            $end .= ';';
            if ($value[$length - 1] !== $end[0])
            {
                return false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    if (($result = @unserialize($value)) === false)
    {
        $result = null;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Step 2:** Use `json_encode` or better yet the method `Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json::serialize()`.