# Product "Save and Duplicate" error

Tags: product, category, magento2.2.3, duplicate

I would like to duplicate the products via Magento admin panel. When I tried to duplicate the product, I'm getting the following error:

"The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists.
To resolve this conflict, you can either change the value of the URL Key field (**located in the Search Engine Optimization section**) to a unique value or change the Request Path fields"

I'm trying to getting the solution to make this work. Please reply with your suggestion. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Note: When I create a new product, the "**Save and Duplicate**" works fine.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you changed the URL key in the search engine optimization section? (As told in error message) Assume that the message gets generated after you hit the Save and duplicate button and when you try to save again?

Comment: Yes, I have changed the URL key as told in the error message. After changing the URL key, I'm getting the following error when I save the product.   

    "Unable to unserialize value."

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194010/magento-2-2-unable-to-unserialize-value