# Magento 2.2.2 REST API - I need to change the customer password using REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, change-password

Magento rest API - I need to change the customer password using REST API.

> In **POSTMAN** application

```
url action :: PUT

http://magento.host/rest/V1/customers/me/password?customerId=146
```

**And i passed integration token in header.**

```
Authorization :: Bearer <Token Value>
Content-Type :: application/json
```

**And In Form-data**

```
customerId :: <customerId>

currentPassword :: <currentPassword>

newPassword :: <newPassword>
```

**webapi.xml code is**

```
<route url="/V1/customers/me/password" method="PUT">
    <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface" method="changePasswordById"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="self"/>
    </resources>
    <data>
        <parameter name="customerId" force="true">%customer_id%</parameter>
    </data>
</route>
```

But it give me error

> {"message":"Decoding error: \nUnable to unserialize value.\n#0
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/Rest/Request/Deserializer/Json.php(64):
>   Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json->unserialize('------WebKitFor...')\n#1
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/Rest/Request.php(141):
>   Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Deserializer\Json->deserialize('------WebKitFor...')\n#2
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php(91):
>   Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request->getBodyParams()\n#3
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(322):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver->resolve()\n#4
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(239):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()\n#5
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#6
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n#7
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#8
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(39):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, Array)\n#9
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135):
>   Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#10
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#11
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()\n#12
>   /var/www/html/rb-dev/index.php(39):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#13
>   {main}","trace":null}

Anyone have any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you get your token? for `/customers/me` endpoints it should be generated from `integration/customer/token` with that customer credentials. Passing customerId in query won't work as magento will disregard it, otherwise you would be able to log in to your account and simply change password to any other customer.

Comment: I generated token using `http://127.0.0.1/rb-dev/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token?username=###&password=###`

Comment: copy paste your request body with dummy values

Comment: In **POSTMAN** Body form-data
`Key  and Value `
customerId => 123
currentPassword =>  test@123
newPassword   => test@345

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have seen you are passing parameter in Form-Data that might be the reason you are facing this kind of issue instead of **Form-data** select parameter as **RAW**  - then choose  **JSON(application/json)** !

Also you are passing **customerId=146**   in URL - so you **actually don't need to pass this in parameter** - as it is for that specific user only so !!

Below i am sharing exact endpoint with parameters which you need to pass in POSTMAN.

Endpoint - **http://magento.host/rest/V1/customers/me/password?customerId=146**

Headers - **Authorization bearer your_access_token**

Content - Type - **application/json**

Body :

```
{
  "currentPassword": "current_password",
  "newPassword": "new_password"
}
```

l

Method Name : **PUT**

For more reference refer this link - https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#!/customerAccountManagementV1/customerAccountManagementV1Change...