# import with import behaviour add/update not working

Tags: magento2, import

Can somebody please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Even if i try to import one row, without any images, with a product that already exists and i want to add/update it, i'm getting the same error always. If checking it says no errors, but if i after checking i click on import it gives the error. I am working with a clean new version of magento 2.2.5, but also tried on 2.1 etc.
If i use replace instead of add/update no problems, but do not want to use that because of the images.

[image]

[image: foutmelding]

Comment: anybody please?

Comment: Have you check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194010/magento-2-2-unable-to-unserialize-value?

Comment: yes i have thanks. Problem is that if i do replace instead of add/update the import works without a problem.