# Unable to serialize value problem with Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.6

Please teach in order to solve the problem.

```
cd /vagrant
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ja_JP
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush;
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex
sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
sudo chown -R :www-data .
sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

> 1 exception(s):
>       Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to serialize value.
>
> ```
> Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to serialize value.
> #0 /vagrant/vendor/magento/framework/App/PageCache/Kernel.php(153):
> ```
>
> Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json->serialize(Array)
>       #1 /vagrant/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(96):
>   Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Kernel->process(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
>       #2 /vagrant/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146):
>   Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->afterRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
>       #3 /vagrant/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
>       #4 /vagrant/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult',
>   Array, Array)
>       #5 /vagrant/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
>       #6 /vagrant/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
>       #7 /vagrant/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
>       #8 {main}

Comment: post code that is getting the error

Comment: have you cleared the caches?

Comment: Yes, I deleted the cache.

Comment: Please follow @Ronak Rathod's answer. It will solve your problem.

Comment: I followed Ronak Rathod's answer, but the problem is not solved. We still need help.

Answer (score 1):

> **The problem is in `/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php` there is a
>   function unserialize($string)**

**There is a workaround - you can check if string is serialized and then use `serialize($string)`. 
Change unserialize to:**

```
public function unserialize($string)
{
    /* Workaround: serialize first if is serialized */
    if($this->is_serialized($string))
    {
        $string = $this->serialize($string);
    }
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
         throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');

    }
    return $result;
}
```

**and add function to check if string is serialized:**

```
function is_serialized($value, &$result = null)
{
    // Bit of a give away this one
    if (!is_string($value))
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Serialized false, return true. unserialize() returns false on an
    // invalid string or it could return false if the string is serialized
    // false, eliminate that possibility.
    if ($value === 'b:0;')
    {
        $result = false;
        return true;
    }
    $length = strlen($value);
    $end    = '';
    switch ($value[0])
    {
        case 's':
            if ($value[$length - 2] !== '"')
            {
                return false;
            }
        case 'b':
        case 'i':
        case 'd':
            // This looks odd but it is quicker than isset()ing
            $end .= ';';
        case 'a':
        case 'O':
            $end .= '}';
            if ($value[1] !== ':')
            {
                return false;
            }
            switch ($value[2])
            {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 9:
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        case 'N':
            $end .= ';';
            if ($value[$length - 1] !== $end[0])
            {
                return false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    if (($result = @unserialize($value)) === false)
    {
        $result = null;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: error is throwed in serialize() function, not unserialize(), so your code has no effect

Answer (score 1):

Please remove var cache as sudo rm -rf var/cache var/page_cache. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please add more description when submiting a Question , when this error showed up and for what reason ?

Possible solutions:

- Clear redis cache :

  redis-cli flushall
- Permissions issue , need to set the **umask** :

> Follow this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/post-install-umask.html)

Check this link for more info [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194010/magento-2-2-unable-to-unserialize-value)

Comment: Could you tell me the command by example?

Comment: What command do you want to know?

Comment: Move to the root directory and run "echo 077 > magento_umask"?

Comment: Better run this command : " echo 022  > magento_umask "

Comment: I confirmed that "echo 022> magento_umask" file was created and the setting was written. I logged in to the administrator screen and confirmed the front end, but the problem was not solved.

Comment: Than Update the two functions based on the link i provided https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194010/magento-2-2-unable-to-unserialize-value *public function unserialize($string) and function is_serialized($value, &$result = null)* From Edmund response

Comment: I have tried but the problem continues.

Comment: Are you using Megamenu by Ves ?

Comment: Is this a function? "http://www.venustheme.com/document/ves-megamenu-12/"
Temple Auto I use is "Ultimo Theme".

Comment: And the error is outputted by the Aheadwork Magento 2 Blog extension.

Comment: I asked if you where using because it was same error as you have https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Unable-to-serial-value-error-after-installing-theme/td-p/102581 , and the fix was provided from the vendor