# Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Unable to unserialize value, string is corrupted

Tags: adminhtml, magento2.3, stores

I haven't made any changes my website was working properly. Magento version is 2.3.1 CE While I was going through configuration options suddenly getting 500 internal server error. Below is error log

> Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Unable to unserialize
> value, string is corrupted. in
> /home/j9pt3t5cpkfw/public_html/check/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Serialize.php:39
> Stack trace: #0 [internal function]:
> Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Serialize->Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer{closure}(8,
> 'unserialize(): ...', '/home/j9pt3t5cp...', 43, Array) #1
> /home/j9pt3t5cpkfw/public_html/check/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Serialize.php(43):
> unserialize('a:1483:{s:11:"p...', Array) #2
> /home/j9pt3t5cpkfw/public_html/check/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/ConfigLoader.php(79):
> Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Serialize->unserialize('a:1483:{s:11:"p...')
>
> ## 3 /home/j9pt3t5cpkfw/public_html/check/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/Environment/Developer.php(79):
>
> Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\ConfigLoader->load('global') #4
> /home/j9pt3t5cpkfw/public_html/check/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(188):
> Magento\Framework\App\Object in
> /home/j9pt3t5cpkfw/public_html/check/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Serialize.php
> on line 39

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/264418/72911

Comment: I have tried that solution but it is not working.Still giving error