# Cannot enable caching with Docker local environment

Tags: magento2, cache, redis

I am getting this error

```
In Serialize.php line 33:

  Unable to unserialize value.
```

However, I do not believe this is the same issue as mentioned in [this thread](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194010/magento-2-2-unable-to-unserialize-value).

I am using Docker for M2 local dev setup. Repo is fully updated, composer dependencies updated. I can run through `setup:upgrade` and `setup:di:compile`.

With caching enabled, I manually flush redis, as metioned in other thread `redis-cli flushall`. Then I run `bin/magento`. Presumably the cache is built in redis... Then again I run `bin/magento`, expecting to see faster performance, however the error is there.

Turns out the `unserialze` method in `/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Serialize.php` is being passed the empty string.

```
public function unserialize($string)
{
    if (false === $string || null === $string || '' === $string) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');
    }
    // ...
}
```

If I add an early return inside that `if` block, like `return null`, the error becomes `The search failed because of a search engine misconfiguration.`, so perhaps search engine config has not made it into redis on first call of `bin/magento`?

Any ideas what is wrong, or how to address?

Answer (score 2):

We are using Magento cloud and it turns out I needed to add the `crypt` value from the cloud environment's `app/etc/env.php` where I took the DB snapshot from to my local `app/etc/env.php` file in order for my local environment to work with said snapshot.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day!