# How to fix composer.json error: Unable to unserialize value?

Tags: magento2.2.6, unserialize

We have installed the third party module and it's working fine. However, when we tried to open the **Mageplaza>SMTP** configuration via the admin panel, I'm getting the below error

[image]

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Refer this link you can helpful for same. 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194010/magento-2-2-unable-to-unserialize-value

Comment: which version to use for Mageplaza>SMTP?

Comment: @SavanPatel 1.2.10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2.2: Unable to unserialize value?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194010/magento-2-2-unable-to-unserialize-value)