# In Checkout while Magento upgrade to 2.3.1 Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to serialize value

Tags: checkout, error, magento2.3, upgrade, magento-2.1.8

Getting below issue at checkout step after upgrade of magento to 2.3.1 from 2.1.8.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to serialize value.

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to serialize value.
<pre>#1 Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage->getSerializedCheckoutConfig() called at [vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml:26]
#2 include('/var/www/project...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#3 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Interceptor#000000001d8c0f290000000035fe6de3#, '/var/www/project...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/project...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:668]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('checkout.root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:533]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('checkout.root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('checkout.root', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:488]
```

Please let me know if someone faced this before.

Comment: Please refer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194010/magento-2-2-unable-to-unserialize-value/265492#265492

Comment: Hello @groy have you found it's solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue on the checkout page while upgrading from 2.2.4 to 2.3.1, and I replace core_config_data table with magento 2.2.4 , now it is working perfectly.

Comment: You just simply truncate the table after upgrading ?