# Magento 2.3.1 exception occured during order load

Tags: orders

How to resolve the issue on Magento 2.3.1 orders grid unable to open in the admin end It throws below error.

> report.CRITICAL:
>   a:1:{s:19:"real_transaction_id";s:22:"5682952820116120004012";}Unable
>   to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error {"exception":"[object]
>   (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0):
>   a:1:{s:19:\"real_transaction_id\";s:22:\"5682952820116120004012\";}Unable
>   to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error at
>   /var/www/html/tupperware/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php:39)"}
>   .

[image]

Comment: It seems like the issue is with the real_transaction_id = 5682952820116120004012 in the order table.

Comment: please check with https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194010/magento-2-2-unable-to-unserialize-value

Comment: Yes @AnasMansuri the issue with the real_transaction_id.  we have migrated m1 to m2 successfully  in M1 real_transaction_id contains serialized  data wherein M2 need json data