# Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Unable to unserialize value

Tags: magento2, unserialize

How to fix this error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Unable to unserialize value. in /home/sbaelect/domains/sbaelectric.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php:52 Stack trace: #0 
/home/sbaelect/domains/sbaelectric.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/CacheManager.php(69): Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json->unserialize('{"Magento\\\\Fram...') #1 
/home/sbaelect/domains/sbaelectric.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(118): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\CacheManager->load('interception') #2 
/home/sbaelect/domains/sbaelectric.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(116): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Config\Reader\Dom\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\Config\Scope), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config), Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Relations\Runtime), Object(Magento\Framework\Interception\ObjectMa in /home/sbaelect/domains/sbaelectric.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php on line 52
```

[image]

and, can't run command line

[image]

[image]

Comment: follow this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194010/magento-2-2-unable-to-unserialize-value

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
->redis-cli
->flushall
->exit
```

Comment: There must be data stored in the db which is hard to unsearlize due to migration or save data. You need to sort it out to fix this.