# Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error after upgrade 2.2.8 to 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, upgrade, cli

After the update process using the Composer has finished I am getting an **Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error** error with any CLI command I try running (like upgrade or cache flush).

---

I followed the guide on [Magento 2.2: Unable to unserialize value?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194010/magento-2-2-unable-to-unserialize-value) and modified already. The error is still there, so I output the string that is serialized into a text file and the result is https://pastebin.com/PaqxNAfA.

This is my unserialize function in `Json.php`:

```
public function unserialize($string)
{

    if($this->is_serialized($string))
    {
        var_dump($string); 
        $string = $this->serialize($string);
    }
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Unable to unserialize value. Error: " . json_last_error_msg());
    }
    return $result;
}

function is_serialized($value, &$result = null) {...}
```

I ran this CLI command to get the string:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean > output.txt
```

Any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it by running these commands:

```
composer update -vvv
redis-cli flushall
bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: I am using centos7 - nginx how to solve this issue?

Comment: You can do the same @zus