# Magento 2 - The product that was requested doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, shipping-methods

Magento2.3.0

I have the following error in `var/log/exception.log` any idea how to come this error

> main.CRITICAL: The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify
>   the product and try again. {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): The
>   product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try
>   again. at
>   /var/www/vhosts/exmp.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php:290)"}
>   []

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This type of error occurs when you delete a product, and try to view the product via an order placed or in the user's order history. Magento can't find it and throws an exception.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that cron job has tried to install any extension and site crashed.

Extension will not installed automatically untill you run composer update or setup: upgrade command.

It may be issue with reindexing. May be cronjob is set you reindexing.

Try reindexing manually once.

**php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

I hope it will help you!

Thanks.

Comment: you have any idea for this error :  main.CRITICAL: Unable to unserialize value. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Unable to unserialize value.

Comment: this error solution is done ?? main.CRITICAL: The product that was requested doesn't exist.

Comment: I have been tring this for the last 2 weeks, it dose not solev, it comes again and again if there is any other solution, tell me about it,

Comment: this error solution main.CRITICAL: Unable to unserialize value. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0):  Please refer this link and https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194010/magento-2-2-unable-to-unserialize-value

Comment: /vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php replace this code  line number 35 >>

public function unserialize($string)
{
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        if(false !== @unserialize($string)){
            return unserialize($string);
        }
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');
    }
    return $result;
}

Comment: Hi, Mohit I am already working on this function, if i replicate this code then i get this error screenshot : https://prnt.sc/r1l4xn

Comment: you are tried to update the composer??