# 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to unserialize value

Tags: magento2, customer, php-7, unserialize, key

[image]

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to unserialize value when i add new customer and open existing customer In Admin side, Error is mention in above screenshot.

Comment: which magento version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Open the this file :- `/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php`

Find:

```
public function unserialize($string)
{
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

replace by:

```
public function unserialize($string)
{
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        if(false !== @unserialize($string)){
            return unserialize($string);
        }
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

And run the `php bin/magento c:f`

And refer this links :-

[Magento 2.2: Unable to unserialize value?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194010/magento-2-2-unable-to-unserialize-value)