# Unable to run magento 2 commands after upgrade

Tags: magento-upgrade, magento2.3.5, command, unserialize

I upgraded magento 2.1.4 to 2.3.5p1. I first upgraded it to 2.2.3 and then to 2.3.5 through command line.

After upgrade, I am getting Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error in /var/www/production/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php:39  on frontend and unable to run any magento command in terminal.

In terminal it gives error  - "Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error"

Please provide a solution to this.

Checked all permissions and ownership also.

[image]

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/265492/85907

Comment: I tried the above link but it changes the error to "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface in /var/www/production/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50  " on frontend.  and PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface in /var/www/production/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50 in terminal

Comment: check this link --- https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/upgrade-to-2-3-2-error-developer-php/td-p/136666 and any problem let me know

Comment: I tried to run the commands but each magento command gives error -" PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface in /var/www/production/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50 "

Comment: Delete your vendor folder and execute `composer update` again

Comment: @Black I deleted vendor folder and ran command composer update, Now it suggests many packages to install like - 
aminas/laminas-validator suggests installing laminas/laminas-i18n-resources (Translations of validator messages)
laminas/laminas-http suggests installing paragonie/certainty (For automated management of cacert.pem)
laminas/laminas-servicemanager suggests installing ocramius/proxy-manager (ProxyManager 0.5.* to handle lazy initialization of services)

Comment: Also, on running any magento command gives fatal error - HP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface in /var/www/production/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50

Comment: there is an error with a configuration in the core_config_data, my best guess is with paypal. Do a backup from the table and delete all the records that are related with paypal or braintree.

Comment: @Rus0 No I searched in core_config_data table there is no row having any data related to paypal or braintree

Comment: Can you post the outcome of just `bin/magento`???

Comment: "Now it suggests many packages to install" And? Just install them, they are needed.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was fixed with below steps.

Edit your **index.php** put this at the start of the file:

```
die('maintenance');
```

to stop requests hitting the box and breaking things. (this can happen even if you are in maintenance mode) edit **app/etc/env.php** make sure:

- deploy mode set to developer
- caches all set to 0
- make sure your composer.json extra contains "magento-force":
  "override"

then run the following:

```
echo "flushall" | redis-cli 
   mkdir vendor_backup 
   mv vendor/magento vendor_backup/ 
   composer install 
   rm -rf generated/* 
   Changing permissions. 
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
   php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production 
   php bin/magento cache:enable 
   php bin/magento cache:flush
```

remove the amends to **index.php**